# How to handle reserved character in REST API with Get request specially & for example value M&S

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, groovy, http-get

I have requirement to accept value as parameter in get request for value like "M&S" but by default after & it consider it as second parameter.

http://myapp:8000?param1=M&S

It still won't work as my postman collection changing as Per URL encoding

http://myapp:8000?param1=M%26S

Answer (score 1):

you have to encode the parameter "&" like below

http://myapp:8000?param1=M%26S

Answer (score 1):

You will have to url-encode the & character. The utf-8 code for that is %26 . So your request will have to be: http://myapp:8000?param1=M%26S